# C API array access modification using sublayer?

Tags: c, api, optimization, macros, compatibility

I have an API function that uses a pointer to a file (quite big) for reading (jumps included, not only continuous reading).

Since I want to use the API for an embedded system with limited resources, it is not possible to provided the complete file to the API at once.

In order to modify in as less code as possible, my idea is to replace the pointers with function calls to a sublayer that fetches the accessed file content to an internal small memory only if it is required (basically a cache).

Note that only bytewise access is required.

For example:

```
currently the API uses: byte = file[some_location];
my idea would be someting: byte = file(some_location);
```

... where "file" is a function call to the sublayer that returns the required byte immediately if it is within the currently loaded file area, or fetches the required area first before returning.

I don't care to much about performance; the raw method is quite slow anyway.

Is this a good idea? And if so, what is a good method to replace the array access with the function calls without the need to modify all the locations in the API?

Comment: Maybe show a bit more of your implementation.

Comment: Are you looking for `lseek()` and `read()`?